# $.grep returning undefined when comparing ID to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a `$.each` loop in my code which loops through items in one array and tries to find corresponding items in another array.
One array is a structure array, with all the items I need. The other array contains only the items which have a value associated.

I tried the following code:

```
$.each(placementStructureHaspItems, function () {
    var haspItem = $.grep(placementValuesHaspItems, function (e) {
        return e.HASPID === this.HASPID;
    })[0];
    if (haspItem != undefined) {
        this.CommentsPreText = haspItem.CommentsPreText;
    }
});
```

`haspItem` is ALWAYS `undefined`, for every object.
I cannot post an image of what I get if I run in a console in chrome, so I will try and format it as best as possible, where the top line is the code entered into chrome and the second line is the result given. :

```
$.grep($scope.HaspitemsFromPlacement, function (e) { return e.HASPID === this.HASPID; })[0];
Undefined

$.grep($scope.HaspitemsFromPlacement, function (e) { return e.HASPID === 2; })[0];
Object {HASPID: 2, ParentID: 1, NumberingType: 0, Text: null, YesNoID: 0…}

this.HASPID
2
```

My main question here is why the grep works with a static number, but not a property of an object which evaluates to the same number.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/): "The function to process each item against. The first argument to the function is the item, and the second argument is the index. The function should return a Boolean value. **this will be the global window object**"

Comment: `===` always expects right hand side value to be equal to the left hand side not only in terms of `value` but also in terms of `type`! like comparing `string` with `string` , `int` with `int` etc., I would suggest either try `==` or try `e.HASPID===parseInt(this.HASPID)`

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks for the answer, but could you explain exactly what you mean by pasting it to me? As far as I know I have used grep correctly, please correct me if I have used it incorrectly.

@Guruprasad - I have just tried both of these with the same results. When ran in chromes console it returns `undefined` just as above unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a global var `HASPID` (which would also be accessible with `window.HASPID`)?

Comment: No there isn't once declared anywhere else. It is only ever a property of the objects and is never declared anywhere throughout my files.

Comment: what will `console.log(e.HASPID)` and `console.log(this.HASPID)` returns?

Comment: This line `function (e) { return e.HASPID === this.HASPID; })` in your `$.grep()` call is equivalent to `function (e) { return e.HASPID === window.HASPID; })` - because of the bold part I've posted in my first comment ;)